# how to make bootstrap4 datatable with dynamic header with scroll search and pagination option

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a Datatable from JSON Data with Dynamic header not static but not getting success i want to render table in `div` only not in table tag because in div tag it populates on full table which looks good on `ui`

i don't know how to make it with dynamic header if anyone have any idea please help me

```js
 var data=[
    {
      "amount": 518212,
      "billdate": "2018-08-04",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 104801,
      "billdate": "2018-08-04",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 138151,
      "billdate": "2018-08-04",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 628358,
      "billdate": "2018-08-05",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 115223,
      "billdate": "2018-08-05",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 134107,
      "billdate": "2018-08-05",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 177866,
      "billdate": "2018-08-06",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 66095,
      "billdate": "2018-08-06",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 284069,
      "billdate": "2018-08-07",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 58789,
      "billdate": "2018-08-07",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 67886,
      "billdate": "2018-08-07",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 313128,
      "billdate": "2018-08-08",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 59939,
      "billdate": "2018-08-08",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 68558,
      "billdate": "2018-08-08",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 321797,
      "billdate": "2018-08-09",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 64431,
      "billdate": "2018-08-09",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 57352,
      "billdate": "2018-08-09",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 323556,
      "billdate": "2018-08-10",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 58772,
      "billdate": "2018-08-10",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 43722,
      "billdate": "2018-08-10",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 464127,
      "billdate": "2018-08-11",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 93110,
      "billdate": "2018-08-11",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 62213,
      "billdate": "2018-08-11",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 626772,
      "billdate": "2018-08-12",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 126933,
      "billdate": "2018-08-12",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 63119,
      "billdate": "2018-08-12",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 167391,
      "billdate": "2018-08-13",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 27110,
      "billdate": "2018-08-13",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 275115,
      "billdate": "2018-08-14",
      "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
    },
    {
      "amount": 58633,
      "billdate": "2018-08-14",
      "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
    },
    {
      "amount": 37920,
      "billdate": "2018-08-14",
      "outlet": "KOLAR"
    }
  ];
  var columndef=[{title:"amount",data:"amount"},{title:"billdate",data:"billdate"},{title:"outlet",data:"outlet"}];
     $('#tbl').DataTable({
        columns:columndef,
      data : data,
          scrollY:        '30vh',
          scrollCollapse: true,
          paging:         true,
          "columnDefs" : [ {
     "targets" : [0],
       className : 'dt-body-left',
     "render" : function(data, type, row) {
      return Number(data).toLocaleString('en-IN', {
       maximumFractionDigits : 2,

      });
      
     }
        
    }]
     
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/sc-1.5.0/datatables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/sc-1.5.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl"></table>
```

i have edited my snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data=[
  {
    "amount": 518212,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104801,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 138151,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 628358,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 115223,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 134107,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 177866,
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 66095,
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 284069,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58789,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 67886,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 313128,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 59939,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 68558,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 321797,
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 64431,
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 57352,
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 323556,
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58772,
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 43722,
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 464127,
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 93110,
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 62213,
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 626772,
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 126933,
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 63119,
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 167391,
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 27110,
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 275115,
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58633,
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 37920,
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  }
];
var columndef=[{title:"amount",data:"amount"},{title:"billdate",data:"billdate"},{title:"outlet",data:"outlet"}];
   $('#tbl').DataTable({
      columns:columndef,
    data : data,
        scrollY:        '50vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table  id="tbl"></table >
```

You should change `div` element to table and create dynamic table definition that's it. Hope this helps.

Comment: hey check UI is not good the headers and there data are mis matching

Comment: @dheerajkumar Let me check

Comment: now the whole page is scrolling which i don't want.. i only want to scroll data inside the table... i have done this and had face the same issue thats why i have put up this question

Comment: @dheerajkumar You are correct , I updated the answer.

Comment: hey bro you there i have a very small doubt?

Comment: @dheerajkumar ya tell me

Comment: look at my code i have edit it ..i want to align all the 'amounts' to right..and i am using right approach also but its not happning

Comment: Do that with column definitions.. Please refer https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes#Cell-classes

Comment: i am doing the same